# Merging arrays with different levels/dimensions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

$array1:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category] => Baggage
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [category] => Camp Dues
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [category] => Extended Care
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [category] => Transportation
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [category] => Trips
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [category] => Tuition
    )

)
```

$array2:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Baggage
   [1] => Cancellation fee
   [2] => Extended Care
   [3] => Transportation
   [4] => Trips
   [5] => Tuition
)
```

What I am trying to do is combine both arrays to look like array 2 find and remove duplicate categories and alphabetize the array. Is there any way to use in conjunction with array_merge to accomplish this?

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Just use a `foreach($array1 as $categoryIndex as $category)` and inside the loop insert each value in another array like: `$array2[] = $category;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php 5+ to `array_column`

```
array_unique(array_merge(array_column($array1, "category"),$array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$array2 = array();
foreach($value in $array1){
    $array2[] = $value["category"];
}
```